# using dlopen to dynamically load x86 android .so file, error with undefined symbol

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to dynamically load an SO file with the following code. The SO file was extracted from an apk that contained x86 and arm version of this SO library (a packed file with mono C# dlls).

```
void * mono = dlopen("./libmonodroid_bundle_app.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(!mono){
    cerr << "Cannot Load Library. Error: " << dlerror() << '\n';
    return -1;
}
```

I firstly got the following error when running my program:

> Cannot Load Library. Error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so

This is due to my libc.so file being a linker script and it is attempting to read it as an actual SO file.

If I manually copy in libc.so using: sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2 libc.so it works. I then had to find an x86 version of liblog.so which I did, also libstdc++.so

Now I've finally got all these libraries I get the following error when calling dlopen:

> Cannot Load Library Error: /libmonodroid_bundle.app.so undefined
>   symbol: __sF

Where is the undefined symbol? I could possibly edit the .so file to remove it via IDA but I suspect it won't function correctly.

LDD output of the .so file I am trying to call below if that helps:

```
ldd -r -v libmonodroid_bundle_app.so 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77fd000)
    libc.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so (0xb6de2000)
    libm.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so (0xb6d8c000)
    libdl.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so (0xb6d85000)
    liblog.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblog.so (0xb6d83000)
    libz.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (0xb6d66000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6bac000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80009000)
undefined symbol: __sF  (./libmonodroid_bundle_app.so)

    Version information:
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Edit: Here is the extern table from IDA and you can see that __sF doesn't point to anything which is strange.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/spI9Lu3.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use a binary which was compiled against Bionic libc (for Android) on a GNU/Linux system, which uses glibc.  These two C libraries are incompatible.

I won't say that it is impossible to do what you are attempting, but achieving your goal is not as simple as copying a few files around.  You need a custom dynamic linker and a shim which translates Bionic libc calls to glibc calls (or raw system calls).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up decompiling the file and extracting the files another way